# i m getting "unbound method" error for this code below

Tags: python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd
class main_class:
    def __init__(self,data_frame):
        self.data_frame = data_frame
    def read_csv(self):
        data_frame = pd.read_csv("outputfile.csv")
        return data_frame
inc = main_class
print(inc.read_csv)
```

By running this code i got unbound method error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is not an error, it's the description of the function.

There are several issues with this code.

- You are printing the function instead of printing the function's return value. In other words, you are never calling the function.
- You are never creating an instance of `main_class`.

To solve the above two issues you need to add `()`:

```
inc = main_class()
#               ^
print(inc.read_csv())
#                 ^
```

Now you will get a `TypeError` error because `main_class.__init__` requires an argument.

- `main_class.__init__` accepts an argument and stores it to `self.data_frame` which is not used anywhere. `data_frame` in `read_csv` is not related to `self.data_frame`.
- And as a side-note, it is preferable that classes in Python 2 subclass `object`:

  ```
  class main_class(object):
      ...
  ```

In the bottom line, you may want to read a Python tutorial to revisit how basic ideas of classes and methods work.